# is it possible to prevent oracle apex from submitting a page until a user clicks on a refresh button on that page?

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex

I have just started working with Oracle APEX and would like users to be able to download reports from my application.The problem is I have a number of reports which have a large number of rows. Each time a user clicks on a page tab, the page is resubmitted and the query for the reports are executed again. This results in a lot of delay and is becoming frustrating for the users!

Is it possible to stop APEX from resubmitting the page until the user clicks a refresh button or is it possible to stop the query for reports from executing everytime the user clicks on a page tab?

Comment: When you click on a page tab you normally end up on a different page - is that so for your application?  If so why is the same report appearing on each page, is it defined on page 0?

Comment: @TonyAndrews, I don't have the same report appearing on each page. Each page has a different report but I don't want the report on the new page to be regenerated unless the user wants this to happen by clicking on a page button. At the moment, the default behaviour results in the query for the report on the new page being executed just because the user has clicked on the page tab. is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes there is.  For example, you can have a hidden item  P123_SHOW_REPORT that has a default value of 'N', and a button called REFRESH that  when pressed redirects back to the same page and sets P123_SHOW_REPORT to 'Y' (or submits the page with a request to branch and set it).  Then put a condition on the report region of type "Value of item in expr1 = expr2" with expr1=P123_SHOW_REPORT and expr2=Y

Comment: @TonyAndrews, thanks for this. I am already using a hidden item to prevent reports being generated the first time a user opens the app. Maybe an example would be more helpful in explaining my needs. Assuming I have an APEX app with Page1 (report 1) & page 2 (report 2). I want to know if there is anything I can do so that APEX does not resubmit the query on Page 1 if the user clicked on Page 2 to see report 2 and then back again on page 1. The reason for this is the report on page 1 might already have been generated and I don't want another delay just generating it again. hope this helps

Comment: So you want the report to still appear, but without re-running the query unless the user presses a refresh button?  You could look at region caching, I'm not sure whether that would meet your needs but it might.

Comment: @TonyAndrews, thats exactly what I need! Will have a look at region caching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent submitting you can change the page template. Open page properties, in the section `Shared Components` find `Templates`. Near the word `Page` you will see a link to its template. Follow this link, then find a section `Standard Tab Attributes`. In the field `Current Tab` you will see something like this:

```
<li><a href="#TAB_LINK#" class="active">#TAB_LABEL#</a>#TAB_INLINE_EDIT#</li>
```

Change this value to:

```
<li><a class="active">#TAB_LABEL#</a>#TAB_INLINE_EDIT#</li>
```

After that an active item in a menu will be displayed as a static text, not as a link.
All pages with this page template will have this behavior. If you don't need to change behavior of all pages: before changing template make copy of it, change the copy and choose the new template in a page properties.

Comment: I tried this it makes it impossible to switch between pages. I am using a two level tab page template. Maybe an example will help describe what exactly I would like to achive. Assuming I have an APEX app with Page1 (report 1) & page 2 (report 2). I want to know if there is anything I can do so that APEX does not resubmit the query on Page 1 if the user clicked on Page 2 to see report 2 and then back again on page 1. The reason for this is the report on page 1 might already have been generated and I don't want another delay just generating it again. hope this helps

Comment: @ontofon Ok. First I thought that you need to prevent resubmitting page 1, when you already are on the page 1 and click on its tab. As I know, APEX stops all page processes (including execution of SELECT queries) when you leave the page. So you need more complex decision, maybe based on application processes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the conditions?? I pretty new with Apex too, I had a similar problem, what I did was put conditions to the buttoms and regions.
After that I good a nice result. Hope it helps you.
Good luck